# How can I efficiently check if a graph is unit distance?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization, performance-tuning

A unit distance graph is a graph that is embeddable in the plane so that every edge has length 1.

```
UnitDistanceQ[input_]:=Module[
    {g, x, F, v, min, nod, gl},
    g = input;
    gl = Length[g]; (* Vertex Count *)
    (* 2 vertex count variables x1, x2, etc... *)
    x = Table[Symbol@@ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 2*gl}]; 
    (* The force to minimize is the squared error of the lengths *) 
    F = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(gl\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(gl\)]g[[i, j]] \((\((x[[2  i]] - x[[2  j]])\)^2 + \((x[[2  i - 1]] - x[[2  j - 1]])\)^2 - 1)\)^2\)\);
    (* Initial vertex positions *)  
    v = Table[gl*Random[], {i, 1, 2*gl}];
    (* Minimization *)  
    {min, nod} = FindMinimum[F, Transpose[{x,v}], Method->"QuasiNewton"];
    (* Output Solution *)       
    If[min < 10^-3,
        Print[{min,nod}];
        GraphPlot[g, VertexCoordinateRules -> 
            Thread[Range[gl] -> Partition[ x /. nod, 2]],
        AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
        VertexLabeling -> None, 
        ImageSize->Small]
    ]
]
```

For example, the [Golomb graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GolombGraph.html) is unit distance.

```
 g = Graph[
          UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 6}, {3, 
             8}, {4, 5}, {4, 9}, {4, 10}, {5, 6}, {5, 10}, {6, 7}, {6, 
             10}, {7, 8}, {7, 10}, {8, 9}, {8, 10}, {9, 10}}];
    m = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
    UnitDistanceQ[m]
    (* gives
        FindMinimum::sdprec: Line search unable 
             to find a sufficient decrease in the function value with 
             MachinePrecision digit precision. >> 
*)
```

So the question is how to check for a unit distance embedding as fast as possible, my code is not working yet but I think something along these lines will work...

My iterative approach works well for the Golomb graph when run many times

[image]

This is a great question and cool algorithms could be invented here!

Comment: Would you kindly explain how the function `UnitDistance` is meant to work?

Comment: It lays out a graph with random vertex positions and then iteratively moves them to decrease the energy functional F which makes every edge become unit distance for instance: Quiet@Reap[
   Table[i = UnitDistanceQ[m]; If[i =!= Null, Sow[i]], {100}]][[2]]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Interesting approach. Btw, if `g` is a graph, you'll want to use `VertexCount` rather than `Length` to determine the number of vertices.

Comment: In my code g is the adj matrix, bad name i guess.

Comment: Ok. That clarifies things.

Comment: Have you seen [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1185448.1185627), [this paper](http://ovid.cs.depaul.edu/documents/realizability.pdf), and [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33043)?

Comment: nice references, thanks @J.M.

Answer (score 7):

Basically along the lines suggested by Bill Simpson. The equation setup could perhaps be done with more elegance. Still, it's fairly short code.

```
isUnitDistance[graph_] := Module[
  {verts, edges, n, coords, p, x, soln},
  verts = VertexList[graph];
  edges = EdgeList[graph];
  n = Length[verts];
  verts = verts /. Thread[verts -> Range[n]];
  coords = Array[x, {n, 2}];
  {x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[2, 1], x[2, 2]} = {0, 0, 1, 0};
  p[j_] := {x[j, 1], x[j, 2]};
  polys = 
   Map[(p[#[[1]]] - p[#[[2]]]).(p[#[[1]]] - p[#[[2]]]) - 1 &, edges];
  Quiet[soln = NSolve[polys]];
  If[soln === {}, False, True]
  ]
```

For run time, don't expect miracles. More than a very few vertices and it could go into overtime.

```
SeedRandom[111111];
gg = Graph@
  Union[Sort /@ (RandomInteger[{1, 8}, {20, 2}] /. {j_, j_} :> 
       Sequence[])]
```

(Still running after 2+ minutes.)

Could try to do similarly using `NMinimize` on sums of squares of distances minus 1. That's just a heuristic though, and a failure to attain a positive result is not a strong indication that no such solution exists.

Comment: Running my original function many times works much faster than this: Quiet@Reap[
   Table[i = UnitDistanceQ[m]; If[i =!= Null, Sow[i]], {100}]][[2]]  However the coordinates are not exact solutions, is there a way to rederive them?

Comment: I prefer the iterative method because of speed but also because you can see the local minima as interesting embeddings in themselves.

Comment: Why not use `RandomGraph`?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to compute whether a graph is a unit distance graph.

However,  if you know the name of a graph you can ask Mathematica directly. For example,

```
GraphData["GolombGraph"]
GraphData["GolombGraph", "UnitDistance"]
```

[image: golomb]

As you may know, graphs that Mathematica classifies as unit distance graphs are the following:

```
Cases[{#, GraphData[#, "UnitDistance"]} & /@ GraphData[], {g_, True} :> g]
Length@%
```

[image: unit distance graphs]

> 454

Comment: I know about GraphData and it is a nice repository, but does not answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, I think maybe that only works for graphs that are already "known" to be unit distance. Maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If your graph is not one of the ones known to *Mathematica* then this might help.

```
e = {(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 == 1, (x1 - x3)^2 + (y1 - y3)^2 == 1,
     (x1 - x4)^2 + (y1 - y4)^2 == 1, (x2 - x3)^2 + (y2 - y3)^2 == 1,
     (x4 - x5)^2 + (y4 - y5)^2 == 1, (x5 - x6)^2 + (y5 - y6)^2 == 1,
     (x6 - x7)^2 + (y6 - y7)^2 == 1, (x7 - x8)^2 + (y7 - y8)^2 == 1,
     (x8 - x9)^2 + (y8 - y9)^2 == 1, (x9 -x10)^2 + (y9 -y10)^2 == 1, 
     x1 == 0, y1 == 0, x2 == 1, y2 == 0};
Reduce[e, {x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5,x6,y6,x7,y7,x8,y8,x9,y9,x10,y10}]
```

That pins a couple of points to the paper and very rapidly determines and returns a couple of choices for positions of some of your subsequent points. You could use that result to fairly quickly determine if there are no satisfactory positions for the rest of your points. Choice of which equations to include has a significant effect on the speed of finding solutions. Sometimes adding an equation will speed it up, others will substantially slow it down. I don't know if you wait long enough whether it would find a solution for all your points.

Comment: This is a nice approach, but I'm trying want a general approximation algorithm: a function to run on any and all graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Simulated annealing will get an algorithm that works the way you want... but will require more careful guidance / tweaking / adaptive adjustment than what I include below:

```
Meas[G_, i_: 0] := Module[{
 Ex = EdgeList[G],
 P = N[PropertyValue[{G, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList[G]]
},
Return[If[i == 0,
 Max[Abs[
  Map[Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] &, 
   Map[P[[#]] &, Map[List @@ # &, Ex], 1], 1] - 1]],
  Max[Abs[
   Map[Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] &, Map[P[[#]] &, Map[List @@ # &,
       Select[Ex, MemberQ[#, i] &]
       ], 1], 1] - 1]]
 ]]
];

STEP[G_, \[Epsilon]_: 0.05, \[Delta]_: 0.1] := Module[{
 Vx = VertexList[G],
 Ex = EdgeList[G],
 n, m, P, i, G2, P2
 },
n = Length[Vx]; m = Length[Ex];
P = PropertyValue[{G, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ Vx;
P2 = P;
i = RandomInteger[{1, n}];
P2[[i]] = P2[[i]] + \[Delta] ({RandomReal[], RandomReal[]} - 0.5);
G2 = Graph[Vx, Ex, VertexCoordinates -> P2];
If[Meas[G2, i] < Meas[G, i] || RandomReal[] < \[Epsilon], Return[G2], Return[G]
]]
```

Unfortunately this won't really work well without some more careful application than using a constant epsilon, delta, `Meas`. It's a random algorithm, it's not necessarily going to work at all, but even so this is a tricky problem. A random graph isn't likely to work, but even then you can see it in action doing, well, something:

```
G = RandomGraph[{15, 20}];
P = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {q, 1, Length[VertexList[G]]}];
G = Graph[G, VertexCoordinates -> P];
DATA = NestList[STEP, G, 5000];
Manipulate[DATA[[i]], {i, 1, Length[DATA], 1}]
```

Short term:

[image: short-term animation]

Long term:

[image: long-term animation]

What is nice is you might see some small unit graphs bouncing around inside the larger graph as you go.

It doesn't even work optimally with a known unit graph:

```
G = GraphData["GolombGraph"];
P = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {q, 1, Length[VertexList[G]]}];
G = Graph[VertexList[G], EdgeList[G], VertexCoordinates -> P];
DATA = NestList[STEP[#, 0.01, 0.2] &, G, 500000];
Animate[ColumnForm[{DATA[[i]], Meas[DATA[[i]]]}], {i, 1, Length[DATA],1}]
```

Short term:

[image: short-term animation]

Long term:

[image: long-term animation]

(Sorry for the artifacts, I had to compress it way too much with some web tool to make it small enough, and so it's a bit tweaked.)

In addition to changing parameters like epsilon and delta, you can adjust the `Meas` metric to be some Lp norm, max, average, whatever you like.